# How to add a completed event when using httpclient to download files?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private async Task Download()
        {
            FilesDownoads downloads = new FilesDownloads(@"d:\testfiles");
            downloads.PrepareLinks();
            using var client = new HttpClient();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    using var s = await client.GetStreamAsync(files[i]);
                    using var fs = new FileStream(@"e:\files1\file" + i.ToString() + ".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                    await s.CopyToAsync(fs);
                }
                catch { }
                
            }
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Download();
        }
```

the goal is to download each file and when the download is completed for each file to do something with the file in the completed event.

i tried to google but still not sure how to add the progress and completed events (mostly the completed ).

Comment: Instead of Stream.CopyToAsync you could use Stream.Read(byte[] buffer, int length, int offset) and then FileStream.Write(byte[] buffer) to write a section at a time

Comment: For a completed event you could just call a function after s.CopyToAsync that updates a Label or List. Could even play a noise